# How to block site security certificates on Internet explorer?

Tags: 8.1, internet-explorer

Since three days, I have been facing problem using internet on my Microsoft Lumia 535 with windows 8.1 as OS. It was normal before that. I removed and put the battery back. Since then, it is showing a disclaimer that site's security certificate wasn't from a trusted certificate authority(Eventhough the site is safe and is with https protocol). It happens whenever I select a link from the address bar and when I try to login into my Stack exchange account.

It shows three options:

1. Go back to previous page.
2. Continue to website (not recommended).
3. Get more information

When I select option 2, it still redirects to previous page. I use Internet explorer as browser.

Is there a way to block these security certificate disclaimer?

Is this a virus or a malware entered into the mobile?